# C#/NET: is there a way to send mail attachments from the Internet without downloading them

Tags: c#, .net, email, attachment

My web app has to send e-mails with HTML files from the Internet attached to them.

Currently I download the files with

```
WebClient.DownloadFileAsync
```

It takes quite a lot because the files are pretty big, it also takes CPU resources and hard drive space.

Is there a way to send online attachments without downloading them first?

Thanks

Comment: Can you link to them instead?

Comment: @LukeH, no, they must be attached. That's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it unless you can send them from the server they are stored in. As fro the disk space, you can delete them after the mail is sent.
Unfortunately that's the best you can do.